# fabric js - objects in generated image have different positioning than the one in the canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to use Fabric js to generate some images with text on it. But for some reason the positioning of the text in the generated image isn't consistent with the one in the canvas. Here's the image as it looks like in the canvas:

[image]

But the generated image looks like this:

[image]

The size I gave to the canvas is 881x640 and its the same with the output size I gave to the image.

Here's what I'm currently doing in my code.

I'm adding the background image into the canvas from the URL. But before I do, I first resize the image to be the same size as the canvas:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(image_source, function(oImg) {
      oImg.width = canvas.width;
      oImg.height = canvas.height;
      canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Then I'm sending the stringified result of the `canvas.toJSON()` call to the node js server to generate the image using AJAX:

```
$.post('http://host:1212', {'canvas': JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON())});
```

In the server side I then load the objects and create the image:

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/uploads/' + file_name);

var body = '';
request.on('data', function(data){
    body += data;
});

request.on('end', function(){

  var request_params = qs.parse(body);

  //set to same size as the canvas on the client side
  var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(881, 640);

  canvas.loadFromJSON(request_params.canvas, function(){
    canvas.renderAll();

    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
    stream.on('data', function(chunk){
      out.write(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function(){
      //close filestream
      out.end();
  });
});
```

Any ideas where could have I gone wrong?

Comment: the images you posted have different heights, is this on purpose?

Comment: the first image is a screenshot from the browser canvas, the second one is the generated image. The reason why they're not the same height is because I didn't do a good job taking the screenshot

Comment: Are you using custom font for these texts? @Kyokasuigetsu

Comment: It seems the same problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926572/fabric-js-displaced-resize-rotate-controls?rq=1

Comment: no I'm not using custom font. Those fonts are the default one's that are available on my machine: helvetica and courier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to add canvas.calcOffset() :

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(image_source, function(oImg) {
      oImg.width = canvas.width;
      oImg.height = canvas.height;
      canvas.add(oImg);

      //HERE
      canvas.calcOffset()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. It turns out there is a bug within fabric.js for rendering on node.  Read about it here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1754.

To fix this, look at node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js - line 19376

```
_getLeftOffset: function() {
  // if (fabric.isLikelyNode) {
  //   return 0;
  // }
  return -this.width / 2;
}
```

Just like above, comment out the if(fabcir.isLikelyNode)...

This fixed it for me.